# Which HTML+Javascript source editors support continuous validation and preview?

Tags: html, javascript, text-editor

For programmers, Eclipse continuously compiles source code and highlights errors as you type. This greatly accelerates edit-test iteration cycles.

I'm looking for a similar sourcecode editor for HTML and embedded Javascript that:

- highlights document errors in the HTML or Javascript source as I type
- has a second view that continuously renders the page as I type

Which tools support these features?

I'm principally interested in speeding up edit-test cycles for Javascript (so I need a source editor, not a WYSIWYG editor).

--- Added:

Even if continuous preview is not supported, are there any source editors available that highlight Javascript errors directly in the source (and let you edit the source)? This would be very useful.

Comment: So close to recommending Dreamweaver but it can't render javascript in Design View...you would have to preview in a browser to test. It meets all of the other requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Jetbrains Webstorm should be up to the task with live edit / in browser HTML highlight.

It will help with the javascript syntax, but will not think for you, but check it out for yourself, it has a 30 day fully function

You can check it out here: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/